# Why parity flag is 1 while number of ones is odd

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, eflags

After executing the following two instructions:

```
MOV BX, 0FD51H                                        
DEC BX
```

I get parity flag = 1 (indicating an even number of ones)

However, the binary representation of the decremented value is:

`1111 1101 0101 0000`

It has 9 ones (i.e, odd number of ones).

Also, executing `NEG BX` after that results in PF = 0. However, the 2's complement is:

`0000 0010 1011 0000` has even number of ones. So I expect PF = 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Intel's manual (section 3.4.3.1 *Status Flags*):

> Parity flag — Set if the least-significant byte of the result contains an even number of 1 bits;
> cleared otherwise.

The least significant byte after `DEC BX` is 50h (i.e. 1010000b), which has an even number of ones. So you'll get PF=1.

Similarly, after the `NEG`, the least significant byte is B0h (10110000b), which has an odd number of ones. So you get PF=0.